# sap ui table max rows visible

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have an OpenUI5 xml view with 2 tables beneath each other.

I want the first one to display 5 rows at a time and the second one to display 20 rows.

What property do I need to set to get this?

EDIT: I'm using a sap.ui.table not the sap.m.table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in case its sap.ui.table.Table then use visibleRowCount='10'
 it will show 10 row data to user and if data is more that 10 it show scroll bar.

Comment: 10 is the default value anyways or not?

Answer (score 3):

To paginate a table these 3 properties are needed:

```
growing="true"
growingThreshold="5"
growingScrollToLoad="false"
```

**growing**:              enables pagination
**growingThreshold**:     maximum rows in one page
**growingScrollToLoad**:  set to false to display page numbers (if this value is true, a lazy loading is implemented)

Comment: The question seems to be more was about sap.ui.table.Table rather than sap.m.Table

Comment: yeah it's sap.ui.table.Table i'll update the question